# How to disable browser auto filling username and password

Tags: html

How do I disable browser auto filling form username and password fields. I have already tried `autocomplete="off"`.

Here is my html

```
<div>
    <p:inputText id="FirstName" value="#{userBean.firstName}"/>
    <p:inputText id="LastName" value="#{userBean.lastName}"/>
    <p:inputText id="userName" value="#{userBean.userName}"/>
    <p:password id="password" value="#{userBean.password}"/>
    <p:password id="confirmPassword" value="#{userBean.password}"/>
    <p:commandButton action="#{userBean.submit}"/>
</div>
```

There is no default values in my bean class. Browser auto fills password field in registration form

Comment: Which version of HTML are you using? And which browser are you testing in? And the form you mentioned is nowhere to be found!

Comment: I am using firefox. Atleast 10 reputations needed to upload an image I am new here.

Comment: check you browser version. for reference check this link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Comment: @Sharanshathiran: Why do you want to post an image?  It's usually better to post the code than a screenshot.

Comment: What @RocketHazmat ^ said. Posting the code means we can copy and test it much easier than an image!

Comment: please post the HTML code to help us better understand your problem and help you.

Comment: Already tried this. I am not taking about autocomplete. My browser auto-fills the registration form with username and password which is the cookie.

Comment: Are you talking about your own code or someone else's code/website? Have you tried clearing your browser's cookies?

Comment: ya if i clear my cookie then browser won't auto fill.